# How to quote the quote marks in strings in u-boot?

Tags: u-boot

Currently my boot string (displayed with `env print`) is:

If I want to set a variable to a string in u-boot, I do

```
env set variable 'my string'
```

But what to do if the string contains the quote characters? I want to put the following into `bootcmd`:

```
if test ${jpsdboot} = 'on' ; then run sdboot; else run emmcboot; fi;
```

If I put the whole string in quotes (either `'` or `"`), it works but the quotes around `'on'` are missing.

If I put it with `\'on\'` it generates a syntax error.

If I put it without quotes, it executes the part after `;` immediately.

How to get the quote marks into the variable value?

Additional info:

What `env print` returns on a "pristine" board:

```
 bootcmd=run usbprod; if test ${jpsdboot} = 'on' ; then run sdboot; else run emmcboot; fi;
```

What my various tries produced:

```
 U-Boot > env set bootcmd 'run usbprod; if test ${jpsdboot} = 'on' ; then run sdboot; else run emmcboot; fi;'
 bootcmd=run usbprod; if test ${jpsdboot} = on ; then run sdboot; else run emmcboot; fi;

 U-Boot > env set bootcmd 'run usbprod; if test ${jpsdboot} = \'on\' ; then run sdboot; else run emmcboot; fi;'
 syntax error

 U-Boot > env set bootcmd run usbprod; if test ${jpsdboot} = 'on' ; then run sdboot; else run emmcboot; fi; 
 Booting from the SD card ...

 U-Boot > env set bootcmd "run usbprod; if test ${jpsdboot} = 'on' ; then run sdboot; else run emmcboot; fi;"
 bootcmd=run usbprod; if test on = on ; then run sdboot; else run emmcboot; fi;

  U-Boot > env set bootcmd "run usbprod; if test ${jpsdboot} = \\'on\\' ; then run sdboot; else run emmcboot; fi;"
  bootcmd=run usbprod; if test on = \\on ; then run sdboot; else run emmcboot; fi;

  U-Boot > env set bootcmd "run usbprod; if test \${jpsdboot} = \'on\' ; then run sdboot; else run emmcboot; fi;"
  bootcmd=run usbprod; if test \\${jpsdboot} = \\'on\\' ; then run sdboot; else run emmcboot; fi;

  U-Boot > env set bootcmd 'run usbprod; if test ${jpsdboot} = \\'on\\' ; then run sdboot; else run emmcboot; fi;'
  bootcmd=run usbprod; if test ${jpsdboot} = \\on\\ ; then run sdboot; else run emmcboot; fi;
```

Comment: You forgot to show the boot string displayed by `env print`. Are you saying that `"if test ${jpsdboot} = 'on' ; then run sdboot; else run emmcboot; fi;"` fails? What if you switch the quotes around and try `'if test ${jpsdboot} = "on" ; then run sdboot; else run emmcboot; fi;'` ?

Comment: @terdon: The original string uses single quotes there, It's exactly what I wrote I wanted to put in there. Maybe I can get double quotes in, but that's not what I want; I want to restore the original. I can give the actual results for the rest...

Comment: I know, I was just suggesting switching them around as a workaround that might let you do what you want. I'm very surprised that using `"` fails though. That makes no sense. In any case, please add the missing line to the beginning of your question.

Comment: Actually, the comparison without quotes works, but I'd still like to know how to get these quotes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
U-Boot> setenv bootcmd 'if test ${jpsdboot} = ' \''on'\' '; then run sdboot; else run emmcboot; fi;'
```

I found this by trial and error. It looks like you need to end the single-quoted string, then add the escaped singe-quote character and open single-quoted string again to continue with your string.

Tested: U-Boot 2015.04